# How to use the domain name of a permanently deleted blog on Blogger?

Tags: gmail, blogger

I created a new Gmail account and a blog on Blogger with it. Then I decided to manage the blog using an old Gmail account.

However, before assigning my old Gmail account as an administrator of the blog, I permanently deleted the blog and the new Gmail account.

Although the Gmail account is restored, the deleted blog can't be restored, and the domain name of the blog is occupied so that the same name can't be used while creating a blog on Blogger by the old Gmail account.

What should I do?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two or more blog with the same name, but you can't create two or more blog with the same url / domain .. If you have a domain and want to link your domain with your new blog, just configurate your domain nameserver

Restore Deleted Blog : https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/10331841?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

get well soon, try to recover the account.